# How to use an iPhone to answer calls of another phone via Bluetooth?

Tags: iphone, bluetooth

I have an iPhone 8 and I would like to use it to answer calls of my older Android phone, which I still keep and I have another line on it. How could I pair my iPhone to the other phone to use the iPhone as a Bluetooth headset?

Comment: If you just want to use it to answer calls, can't you just forward the Android calls to the iPhone?

Comment: No, the operator will not do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not something you can do, at least without jailbreaking it.